# What are the design disadvantages of a monowheel landing gear setup which might have led to its historic rejection?

Tags: landing-gear

Monowheels have a lot to be said for them, which is why we [use](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.f6b6a478903cd5f327f4fc1caff58eb4?rik=Rjeav3nqXBblsg&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) [them](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7e/14/58/7e1458d7e8edf994af7994672100ad15.jpg) [in](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a13064cf8d37d7e15ecef80cd644be03?rik=h4U%2Ft4Y4j1QLyw&riu=http%3A%2F%2Fcrosscountrysoaring.com%2Fimages%2Flanding_1.jpg&ehk=0YoH15ZsIEUn5qy5bw%2BiE4%2B1LOzBmvbv2E4FCtSWlpg%3D&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0&sres=1&sresct=1) [gliders](https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.nOp_PCID8H2keC6DxDj_9AHaE8?pid=ImgDet&rs=1). They save weight, drag, and cost, are tolerant of tire failures, and [frequently](https://youtu.be/xp0kf2zRhwQ?si=I4WuN_kZhJi8qZKu&t=1177) [handle](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sfqP5cp3rzQ/maxresdefault.jpg) [outlandings](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pBm9HYLZhiw/maxresdefault.jpg) with aplomb.

However, they have not proven to be popular outside of gliders. There are very few examples of them, with only the [Europa XS](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.e70002994617750913a4f5d1407d33ff?rik=XSa5cAXpFB%2FOTQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0), the [B-52](https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a5fac57179031160b8e1f67fcd11c7aa?rik=sH2eEyxTy0r17w&riu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.richard-seaman.com%2FWallpaper%2FAircraft%2FBombers%2FB52LandingGearDown.jpg&ehk=%2BMKetORbQ9ga10Sh5HiOsVNHEKdmnM%2FNqS%2BJx2RKIJs%3D&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0), and the [U-2](https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/56cab28/2147483647/strip/true/crop/2048x1365+0+0/resize/1440x960!/quality/80/?url=https:%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2F44%2Ff3%2Fed5c9c9c731e05453d6e17531f47%2Fla-na-u2-spy-plane-pictures-20150826-009) as modern(-ish) examples I can think of. (And even the Europa XS sales have now shifted largely over to tricycle gear.)

Below is a [monowheel variant](https://www.europa-aircraft.co.uk/europa-xs-monowheel.html) of the Europa XS:
[image]

And here's a landing B-52 (technically not a *monowheel*, but still a *centerline* gear configuration), with the outrigger supporting the starboard wing:
[image]

While it can be argued that maybe the relative absence of monowheels is because pilots are a conservative sort and will only fly things that "look right", that's a less compelling argument when someone says "your job is on the line". If the monowheel were better for a broad class of planes, the logical conclusion is that there would be commercial pressures which would lead to their broader introduction.

(This would have been especially true in wartime 1940s when rubber was notoriously hard to come by and minimizing the number of tires would have had instant payoff.)

Perhaps the technology to enable monowheels' theoretical superiority wasn't (and still isn't?) present? With the exception of gliders, outriggers are necessary, and those would be dramatically smaller and less draggy with modern composites as opposed to, say, chunks of wood or steel.

Anyone have any hard data on this? Surely NASA, or NACA, or some early airplane manufacturer must have dabbled in this and written down their findings...

Comment: The U-2 was specialized for one and only one purpose, so its landings are not great examples of successful or failed gear topologies, but boy is this video fun: https://youtu.be/eamnTyfkUBY?si=bD__Gj58ftYYTQGu&t=70

Comment: B52 is definitely not a monowheel, it has 4 main landing gears (each with two tires) and 2 on the wing tips.

Comment: @sophit yes, see my comment in response to your answer. It's possibly a scaling concern. However, it embraces the monowheel approach, where the main wheels are close together that it is not fully stable while on the ground, and needs outriggers to support the wings.

Comment: Building on your point, if we define "monowheel" as anything which requires outriggers (and maybe this isn't a fair and reasonable definition), there are a wide variety of "monowheel" configurations, incl. main-and-tailwheel (most gliders), main-and-nose-and-tailwheel (ASK21), bicycle (Harrier), quad truck (B52), and maybe more?

Comment: The monowheel question was pretty much answered by @sophit (unless you disagree), so by continuing the discussion it seems that you are expanding the question to bicycle landing gear. Which is fine but you may want to clarify that in the question. If I am reading into your question and comments correctly, while currently there may be practical reasons for tricycle landing gear over bicycle, your question is if future technology allowed it, would bicycle landing gear possibly become a thing, is that right?. I'm thinking of the Segway, a design that required new technology to make it work.

Comment: @StevePemberton see my definition of "monowheel". If there's a better word to catch all the configurations which require outrunners, lemme know and I'll update the question. Re your question, I'm mostly just curious why something which seems simpler and more robust, wasn't actually. (I'm assuming that if monowheels had been awesome solutions, we would have many of them out there.) This could possibly be because of continuing issues with it; or because during the period of rapid innovation (through the 1940s?) the tech didn't exist to overcome some key obstacle.

Comment: @StevePemberton I would not say that sophit has answered the question. You can see my comment on his answer, but in short while it gives some specific insight into massive jetliners, there is a wide range of designs which exist between gliders and jetliners. And, yet, vanishingly few use a monowheel/tandem/bicycle topology.

Comment: Thanks for adding the photo.  That looks like a prop strike waiting to happen though!

Comment: @MichaelHall I thought so, too. Doesn't look so bad from this angle, though: https://www.airliners.net/photo/untitled/europa-xs-monowheel/1681781 And the tricycle variant doesn't seem to have any additional clearance: https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.e5cdc62de26d6acc2f49087b2af0cca6?rik=j%2fxZIeTohPDsZQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0

Comment: KennSebesta - I think I see what you are saying. Tail-dragger and tricycle gear have side-by-side main landing gear bogies. They may also have additional center gear under the fuselage (MD-11). You are describing planes with center main landing gear only. In some cases monowheel ( Europa XS), in other cases two-wheel center bogie (U-2), in other cases tandem center bogies (B-47).  I think the B-52 may not be a good example however because even though it has bicycle main gear and outriggers and visually has a "centered" look, it does not have center gear, only side-by-side main gear bogies.

Comment: @StevePemberton is monowheel perhaps the wrong way to describe this? Maybe "centerline" is better, since the concept is that there are planes which will prone to tipping onto a wing in typical wind conditions, and planes which will not. Those which are then either have outriggers (Europa, U-2, B-47, B-52), or skids (gliders) to protect the wing.

Comment: KennSebesta - centerline might be good, defined as one or more landing gear struts centered under the fuselage, with no side-by-side struts. I don't think I would include outriggers in the definition as those are merely technical solutions that deal with stability.  The AN-124 landing gear for example has a lot of similarity with the B-52, however because of its wider fuselage it does not require outriggers.

Comment: B52s are most certainly stable on the 4 main trucks. The outrigger gear on the wing tips is not for stability, it is to keep the wing tips from dragging on the ground. The wings of the B52 are very flexible. As they contain large fuel tanks, when the tanks are full, the wings droop considerably. When the tanks are nearly empty, the wings lift and the outrigger gear will be several feet in the air.

Comment: @Jim fascinating! Do you have a background link on that? I went looking and found this picture, which presumably is from a landing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDaDV.jpg. Pretty clearly, that outrigger is keeping the starboard wing from dragging, while the port wing is extremely elevated.

Comment: @KennSebesta I worked maintenance on B52G while I was in the USAF. whenever the wing fuel tanks were low or empty, the wing would raise up and the outrigger would be off the ground. in fact if the wind was variable, gusting, the wing would move up and down. very annoying if you were working on it. most of the time we kept fuel min the wing tanks to prevent this. That is why most pictures will show the gar on the ground.

Answer (score 8):

If an A380 landed on one wheel only it would leave a groove so deep that the runway should be rebuilt after every landing.

A standard civil tarmac runway can sustain tires with a maximum inflation pressure of 7-8 bar (100-120 psi - a tarmac runway couldn't survive a [Grand Tour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour_(cycling)) race ). On grass the maximum pressure might be half of that value. Multiplying this maximum inflation pressure by the footprint area of the tire we get the maximum weight that each tire can bear before ruining the landing strip. Given the total weight of the aircraft, we can then decide to spread it either on few big wheels (one single wheel as an extreme case) or many small wheels.

For a jetliner the second option (many small wheels) is the preferred one due to several reasons:

- it gives a more compact design for the landing gears;
- the design is redundant; should one wheel get damaged the other ones can sustain its share of weight without damages;
- smaller wheel implies less inertia to start rotating at touchdown;
- they can be inflated at a lower pressure increasing their life.

---

Just for fun, let's see what tire our monowheel A380 would need. According to [this NASA report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930084870), the footprint area $A_p$ of a tire can be estimated via the following empirical equation:

$A_p=0.45d²$

where $d$ is the nominal diameter (in inches). This is the equation 12 in the report with the additional assumptions that under load the tire gets squashed of 1/3 of its diameter and that its width to diameter ratio is 1/3 too.

Using the maximum 120psi allowed for a civil landing strip and the 1'200'000lbf of an A380 we get:

$A_p=1'200'000/120=10'000=0.45d² \Rightarrow d=150 in$

Well, a very big wheel indeed!

Comment: Technically, an A380 could still land on only one wheel, you'd just need to make it very very large

Comment: @MikeB: it would be more practical to simply slide on the belly 

Comment: @sophit, that's an excellent point about scaling effects. Building on your point, the B52 isn't a true monowheel, since it has a series of wheels narrowly grouped together. However, a single main wheel seems to be compatible for lightweight GA and even the U2, so scaling effects alone cannot be the cause. Do you have any data about where the crossover point is, where a wide enough, tall enough tire would no longer fit into the airplane? As you point out, gliders are light enough not to have an issue, and so presumably are many (most?) GA airplanes.

Comment: I think the "cross-over point" is roughly the U2. Is there anything larger that's configured with true bicycle gear? As noted several times, the B52 is _not_ bicycle gear - it's got 4 main gear that just happen to be mounted close together and attached to the fuselage.

Comment: Even the U2 doesn't use a single wheel - both the fore and aft undercarriage has two tyres side by side

Comment: @sophit, I see where you're going with this, but, based on the data given, your conclusion "In general for an aircraft heavier than a glider, monowheel is something impractical." is a bridge too far. My question was for all non-gliders, but this answer is specific only to jetliners. There are many, many great design choices which wouldn't work on jetliners, such as single engine piston propulsion, unpressurized cabins, single tires on each main, floats, tailwheel etc... So no argument for why monowheels wouldn't work on jetliners, but what about the "everything else"?

Comment: @sophit thanks for the changing that part, and I really appreciate the worked example for the A380 tire. Is MTOW on a jetliner a fair approximation for maximum force on landing, or would it need to be higher to accommodate for rough landings? BTW, here's a 108" dia tire on a US prototype bomber: https://www.sim-outhouse.com/sohforums/showthread.php/31195-Bristol-100-ton-bomber?s=ca565feee69d4046b6845cddc400de7b&p=355274&viewfull=1#post355274 I wonder if we can get DALL-E to do some concept art of what that A380 would look like with a monowheel? :D

Comment: I'm gonna call bullshit on tarmac not surviving a Grand Tour event...

Comment: If that was intended as a joke, then yes 

Comment: @Jpe61: done 

Comment: 150" isn't that large - mining truck tires reach that size. It's other impracticalities that make it pointless and dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

There are some serious show stoppers before you even get started.

The biggest problem for monowheels is, if you want minimalist outriggers near the wing tips to really gain the drag or structural benefit of a single main wheel, you you need a maneuvering path that is wider than the plane's wingspan. And even if you do find a taxiway that is wide enough, unless it's WAY wider, you need a center line to follow to avoid driving your outriggers into the weeds.

And if you move the outriggers inboard to make it able to operate from narrow taxiways, they have to be much more robust, and you are creeping toward regular landing gear now, except you have three units, one big middle one, and two smaller ones outboard. Might as well do it the regular way and do away with those hassles, which is the reason almost nobody does that configuration outside specialized cases.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149430/discussion-on-answer-by-john-k-what-are-the-design-disadvantages-of-a-monowheel); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> not proven to be popular outside of gliders

The reason may be the ability to land and take off from less than ideal surfaces.

Two strong wheels and a tail-skid was the [norm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_JN_Jenny) for the first 50 years of aviation.  Many "airfields" of this time were little more than closely cropped stretches of grass.

Paved runways opened the door to not only monowheels, but also nose wheels.  But weakly designed landing gear simply won't [cut it](https://www.flyingmag.com/tundra-tire-nation) out in undeveloped areas, where a mechanical breakdown means you're stranded.

Two main wheels also offer the possibility of [differential braking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/what-is-differential-braking) to improve ground control.

Comment: That's an interesting point about ground control. Maybe after much experimentation there was no satisfactory manner to steer on the ground without either a short-coupled nosewheel or two wheels with differential braking?

Comment: Taxiing a mono wheel in a cross wind may not be easy, but a weight savings of 100 lbs is of interest.